# How to solve Ax=b with matlab where A is a large unsymmetric sparse matrix?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I'm doing with `Ax = b` where A is very large (over 1m*1m size), non-symmetrical sparse matrix in `matlab`. I build `A` in sparse way. However, using `A\b` directly is too slow. I tried `gmres`. However, without pre-conditioner I cannot get the right answer and with pre-conditioner (`ilu` for instance) it's also too slow.

How can I solve this problem efficiently? Thx.

Comment: It depends on a lot of parameters. How many times do you do this computation? Do you always use the same matrix `A` and solve for different values of `b`?

Comment: 1. I do the computation just for once use.
2. No. I generate `A` and `b` everytime I run the program.

Comment: Well, Matlab is already quite optimized for linear algebra problems, and it's pretty normal it's slow for very big matrices. I don't see any way your calculation could be fast. The only lead i'd have would be to use `linsolve` if your matrix has specific properties

Comment: have you seen this http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lsmr/ ?

Comment: Maybe I can program in C/C++ .....

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to give a definitive answer, since it depends on the particulars of the system you are solving. Unfortunately this involves a lot of trial and error on your side and there is no guaranteed method that will work for any system. Here are a few things to consider:

1. How sparse is the system and how slow is `too slow`? 1M x 1M is  a fairly large system, but the work depends on the number of non-zeros; so if your system has many nonzeros, then yes, it will take a while to run; another aspect that could lead to a long running time is the poor numerical conditioning of your system (see [1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConditionNumber.html) and [2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ill-ConditionedMatrix.html)); preconditioning should help with this, as long as you use an effective preconditioner
2. Try a different iterative method: for example the [BiCG method](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bicg.html) or [BiCGStab](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bicgstab.html), which should also work for unsymmetric systems
3. Try to tweak the [ILU](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ilu.html) pre-conditioner or use a different preconditioner: increasing the drop tolerance will result in a sparser pre-conditioner which may affect convergence, but reduce total work per iteration (values smaller than the drop tolerance are removed from the sparse matrix during factorization); you could also tweak the type of the precodntiioner `ilu(0)`, `crout`, `ilutp`;
4. Make sure you are using parallel and optimised implementations of the BLAS libraries, such as the Intel MKL Blas or at least Open BLAS; this should speed up the direct method a fair bit
5. Finally you could try to use a different framework; other frameworks also allow you to select directly the level of fill-in of the ILU preconditioner (giving you more options to explore, which result in a denser preconditioner, but with better convergence behaviour); other frameworks like PetSC also support a wider range of [preconditioners](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/PC/) and [iterative solvers](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/linearsolvertable.html);